# SQL Server table to table bulk insert using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to insert around 5 million rows of data from one table to another using C#. Please recommend a good way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Give it a try and let us know if you run into any issues after you've got what you think should be a working solution.

Comment: I am getting timeout exception when i try to do the below way                                     INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;

Comment: Why are you doing this in C# - simply to provide a front end?

Comment: Its a job actually and doing lots of process in between so i cannot seperate

Comment: I'd write a stored procedure. N.B. if you drop or disable the indexes, it would make the insert faster.

Comment: You should be able to increase the timeout in your C# code. Are you able to post what you have so far?

Comment: Is it a good way to increase the timeout ??

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while but I believe you can either set the time out on the connection or command but we'd need to see at least some stub code to advise further.

Answer (score 0):

write a Stored Procedure or query and then run it from C# code.

the query will look like this -

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```